# TreeView with inherited types

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I want to display a TreeView containing elements implementing an interface. This interface is implemented by two main classes, which are the ones I want to display.

The schema is something like:

```
IElement
    Container : IElement
      ->public IEnumerable<IElement> Elements {get; set;}
    Element : IElement
```

So basically, this TreeView must be able to display Containers and Elements on any level. Containers should be "expandable" (since they contain other IElements), but Elements should not.

So [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1854977/3283203) doesn't seem to fit, since it's setting two completely different levels (Enterprise/Employees).

I don't see how I can fill a TreeView with IElements while being able to check weither they're Containers or Elements, and how to prevent expansion of only one of these types.

Comment: Test whether the element is a Container: `if (element is Container) ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this something along the lines of what your looking for ?
here's a sample :

CS :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<IElement> Elements
    {
        get
        {
            var list = new List<IElement>();

            list.Add(BuildContainer());
            list.Add(BuildContainer());
            list.Add(new Element());

            return list;
        }
    }

    private Container BuildContainer()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.Elements.Add(new Element());
        container.Elements.Add(new Element());

        var sub_container = new Container();
        sub_container.Elements.Add(new Element());

        container.Elements.Add(sub_container);

        return container;
    }
}

public interface IElement
{
     string Title { get; }
}

public class Container : IElement
{
    public string Title
    {
        get { return "Container"; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<IElement> elements;
    public ObservableCollection<IElement> Elements
    {
        get
        {
            if (elements == null)
            {
                elements = new ObservableCollection<IElement>();
            }
            return elements;
        }
    }
}

public class Element : IElement
{
    public string Title
    {
        get { return "Element"; }
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
<Window
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Element}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Red" FontSize="14"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Container}" ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" />
</Grid>
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: It looks easy when someone else does it. That's exactly what I'm looking for. And it made me understand the use of HierarchicalDataTemplate and DataTemplate in a TreeView. Many thanks.

Comment: now here's a challenge for you , lets say you have only one root node and you want it to look completely different.

Comment: I must say I lack knowledge on the TreeView. It doesn't seem to have anything specific to access the root node's styling;

Comment: @Kilazur if this helped you , you should except the answer

Answer (score 0):

Add one more property `IsExpandable` of type `bool` to your `IElement` `interface`. Set this property to `true` for `Container` class only and use this property in `Binding` or `Trigger` for your `TreeViewItem`.